# Google's PageSpeed Insights complains when I follow instructions from Google Fonts FAQ. Which should I follow?

Tags: html, css, webfonts, pagespeed

If I run Google's PageSpeed tool on my site it complains that I have blocking CSS resources (which is true, I understand that).  The thing is it is complaining about is a google font that I am using by following the instructions on their FAQ [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq).

Specifically:

> Should I host fonts on my own website’s server?
>
> We recommend copying the code snippets available under the "Embed" tab
>   in the selection drawer directly into your website’s HTML and CSS.

So that is what I'm doing - but that also generates the warning on PageSpeed.  So specifically, I have this in my `head` tag (as per the embed tab's instructions):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

I could download that font and bundle it pretty easily (I'm using Angular-CLI if that makes any difference).  I imagine that would get rid of the warning on PageSpeed, but then (I assume) my page would actually be less efficient because I wouldn't be using Google's CDN for their font and wouldn't benefit from browsers caching it.

Which pattern should I use?  Is there a good way to take advantage of CDNs for CSS without having your PageSpeed ranking reduced?  (I care because I understand it impacts Google's search rankings or I'd just leave it as it is).

Comment: I'm doing my researches here also, for me this is totally new.

Comment: Sites like Google usually have better servers than you do

Comment: @YuriRamos I know - that's why I'd prefer to just leave it like it is, but then I'll be demoted in their search results.